# Why is an expression of this sort "Obj<A> x = new Obj<B>();" causing compilation error, if B is subclass of A?

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors

I am trying to run this code:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class Obj<T> {
    private T c;
    public void set(T a) {
        c=a;
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Obj<A> a = new Obj<B>();
    }
}
```

And I am getting the following Exception:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from Obj<B> to Obj<A>`
Should't it be able to work if B is a subclass of A?

Comment: `B` is a subclass of `A`, but `Obj<B>` is not a subclass of `Obj<A>`

Comment: Because `Obj<A>` would allow the use of *any* subclass of A, instead of restricting the object to only using B as the construction intended.  You can, however, write `Obj<? extends A> a = new Obj<B>;`.  But then the `set` method would be unusable for that object, since the compiler wouldn’t know exactly which types are safe to pass.